# Composing monad transformer stacks

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Suppose I have two Haskell libraries, each with one type for computations, `LibA` and `LibB`. They are both monads stacked on top of the IO monad, implemented with the `ReaderT` monad transformer:

```hs
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (MonadIO)
import qualified Control.Monad.Reader as MR
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader (runReaderT)

newtype LibA a = LibA (MR.ReaderT String IO a)
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO)

newtype LibB a = LibB (MR.ReaderT String IO a)
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO)
```

Programs expressed with these libraries are executed with `runReaderT`:

```hs
runA :: String -> LibA a -> IO a
runA s (LibA x) =
  runReaderT x s

runB :: String -> LibB b -> IO b
runB s (LibB x) =
  runReaderT x s
```

Now suppose I want to write an application that uses both libraries.

When used independently, these work:

```hs
runA "conf" (return (2 :: Int)) :: IO Int
```

```hs
runB "conf" (return "foo") :: IO String
```

However, using one within the other does not:

```hs
runA "conf" $ do
  -- Expected: LibA String, Actual: IO String
  runB "conf" (return "foo")
```

This is because `runB` returns in the IO monad.

So instead I can lift this into `LibA` with `liftIO`:

```hs
runA "conf" $ do
  liftIO (runB "conf" (return "foo"))
```

Here's how it fits together:

[image]

I have two issues with this: (1) compositionality, and (2) resource efficiency.

### Compositionality

Suppose an application needs to use computations from monads `LibA` and `LibB` in an interleaved fashion. The code becomes unwieldy:

```hs
runA "conf" $ do
  liftIO $
    runB "conf" $ do
      liftIO $
        runA "conf" $ do
          liftIO $
            runB "conf" $ do
              return "foo"
```

### Resource efficiency

For real world libraries, `runA` and `runB` might initialise resources before running application code. E.g. establishing then releasing connections to web servers, file IO, etc. Deeply nested `runA` and `runB` calls will create lots of unnecessary resource handling.

For example, suppose `runA` creates a HTTP connection `Manager` to maintain one connection to a web server:

```hs
runA :: String -> LibA a -> IO a
runA s (LibA x) =
  let settings = mkManagerSettings (TLSSettingsSimple True False False) Nothing
  manager <- liftIO $ newManager settings
  runReaderT (MySession x manager) s
```

where actions in `x` can obtain the manager from the ReaderT context with `ask`, to reuse the one `manager`.

The [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.3.8/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v:newManager) for `newManager` states:

> Creating a new Manager is a relatively expensive operation, you are advised to share a single Manager between requests instead.

So when interleaving `runA` and `runB` executions, I don't want repeated calls to `newManager`, I want a manager to be created only once for all `LibA` computations, even those lifted from within nested `runB` calls.

### Solutions?

What I'm after is a composable way to interleave `LibA` and `LibB` computations without nested `liftIO` calls, and without creating/releasing IO resources multiple times. They are both stacked directly on top of the IO monad, so this isn't beyond the realms of imagination. I have no way of modifying the library implementations.

E.g. something like:

```hs
runAB :: (String, LibA a) -> (String, LibB b) -> IO (a, b)
```

which would create the relevant IO resources for `LibA` and `LibB` actions only once.

Alternatively if that resource efficiency isn't possible, then for readability simply an allowance to write code more directly as if they were both stacked within one monad stack on top of the IO monad:

```hs
runA "conf" (runB "conf" (return "foo"))
```

What are the options?

Comment: I'm not sure but isn't this what monad transformers are for? So LibA and LibB would have to define transformer versions of their monads and you could make a monad with properties of both LibA and LibB

Comment: If you know they are both ReaderT then you can make your own stack and have some ugly code to get and put the states; if you don't know what the monads are, then you can't compose them because monads in general cannot be composed.

Comment: I think you are trying to re-discover the [ReaderT pattern](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/06/readert-design-pattern/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you use polymorphic code over the monad stack. Instead of using `transformers` directly, you use `mtl`-style. It depends on how you structure your code (below i'm using the `RIO` pattern), but the general idea is:

```hs
-- Fake types for Environments
type Manager = String
type FileHandler = String

-- Fake for the sake of example
type Settings = String
type Path = String

-- For the sake of example let say LibA has a Manager and LibB a FileHandler 
newtype LibA a = LibA (ReaderT Manager IO a)
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO)

newtype LibB a = LibB (ReaderT FileHandler IO a)
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO)
  
-- You'd like to have these two
runA :: String -> LibA a -> IO a
runA s (LibA x) =
  let settings = mkManagerSettings (TLSSettingsSimple True False False) Nothing
  manager <- liftIO $ newManager settings
  runReaderT x manager -- run x using the manager as a global environment

runB :: String -> LibB a -> IO a
runB s (LibB y) =
  fhandler <- liftIO $ getFileHandler -- imagine this exists.
  runReaderT y fhandler -- run x using the file handler
```

But as you can see, it is very clumsy when you pour LibB into x or LibA into y. So you better be polimorphic in the environment and the monad you use. Do not write any of your functions using directly `LibA` or `LibB` This is very similar to OOP design patterns: "rely on abstractions not on concrete implementations"

The way to proceed (again, it depends on how do you structure your app) is to change all functions relying on `LibX` to rely on its abstract effects. Let me show

Imagine you have two functions. one for `LibA` and one for `LibB` and you want to chain them together. Somethin like below

```hs
-- Let say you have a function for managing session_ids using LibA
-- which has the resource
computeA :: Int -> LibA String -> IO String
computeA session_id manage_session_id = do
  runA ...

-- And a function for LibB which logs a message
computeB :: String -> LibB String -> IO ()
computeB log_message message_logger = do
  runB ...

-- This doesn't work
computeA 42 >>= computeB
```

As you already know, you can't chain them. The point is that if you define `computeA` and `computeB` in terms of "what they can do" then, they compose.

```hs
--           |- A monad with a global env
--           |                  |- env has a Manager
--           |                  |               |- the monad can do IO
computeA :: (MonadReader env m, HasManager env, MonadIO m) 
         => Int -> m String
computeA session_id = ...

-- change that function to
--           |- A monad with a global env
--           |                  |- env has a FileHandler
--           |                  |                   |- the monad can do IO
computeB :: (MonadReader env m, HasFileHandler env, MonadIO m) 
         => String -> m ()
computeB session_id = ...

-- This does work!!!
computeA 42 >>= computeB
```

Finally in the main function you initialize everything

```hs
-- Extra boilerplate not here. Look at the full example below
data Env = Env {fileHandler :: FileHandler, manager :: Manager}
newtype Lib a = Lib (ReaderT Env IO a)
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO, MonadReader Env)

run :: Env -> Lib a -> IO a
run env (Lib x) = runReaderT x env

main :: IO ()
  m <- newManager
  f <- newFileHandler
  let env = Env f m
  run env (computeA 42 >>= compute B)
```

You notice that you need some boilerplate. For example, classes `HasManager` and `HasFileHandler`. This is done, because generally you want to be polymorphic on the enviroment type.

Here you have fully working example in the playground: https://play.haskell.org/saved/gCFK2jFj